# swift NSPredicate compare string

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nspredicate

In the twitter api, the id_str is like this: `"572581876033982465"`.

Right now I want to use `NSPredicate` to filter the tweets, and the current format is like this:

`NSPredicate(format: "idStr > %@", self.maxId!)`

Both `idStr` and `self.maxId` are type of `String`. And it crashes with error message: `"Operator type 2 not supported for string type"`.

I think it means that I should cast both of them to number value.

I tried this:

`let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "[idStr intValue] > %@", self.maxId!.toInt()!)`

But it crashes with error:
`Unable to parse the format string "[idStr intValue] > %@`

How to cast the id_str in the format?

Comment: `"(idStr.integerValue > %d", self.maxId!.toInt()!)`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
let id_str = "572581876033982465"

let id_num = id_str.toInt()!

var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id_num > %@", self.maxId!.toInt()!)
```

Comment: But idStr is a property of a class.